# Kubectl get deployments shows No resources found in default namespace

Tags: kubectl

[I am trying my hands on Kubernetes and I tried to deploy an image into k8s service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbfFO.jpg)

```
root@KubernetesMiniKube:/usr/local/bin# kubectl run hello-minikube --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.10 --port=8080
pod/hello-minikube created

root@KubernetesMiniKube:/usr/local/bin# kubectl get pod

NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-minikube   1/1     Running   0          16s

root@KubernetesMiniKube:/usr/local/bin# kubectl get deployments

No resources found in default namespace.
```

Why i am seeing No resource found but actually there is a resource running inside default namespace.

Comment: you are using never version, when you are using `run` it will create a pod. You need to use `kubectl create deployment hello-minikube --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.10`. I will provide give you more details soon as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using `$ kubectl run` it will create a [pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/).
In your example thats exactly what happned, it created `pod`, named `hello-minikube`.

```
pod/hello-minikube created
```

If you want to create [deployment](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/deployment)

> Deployments represent a set of multiple, identical Pods with no unique identities. A Deployment runs multiple replicas of your application and automatically replaces any instances that fail or become unresponsive.

you can do it using command:

```
$ kubectl create deployment hello-minikube --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.10 --port=8080
deployment.apps/hello-minikube created
user@cloudshell:$ kubectl get deployments
NAME             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
hello-minikube   1/1     1            1           8s
```

You can also create `deployment` using [YAML](https://yaml.org/).
Save YAML from [this documentation example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment) and use `kubectl apply`.

```
$ vi nginx.yaml 

<paste proper YAML definition. Also you can use nano editor, or download ready yaml>

user@cloudshell:$ kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment created
$ kubectl get deployments
NAME               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
hello-minikube     1/1     1            1           3m48s
nginx-deployment   3/3     3            3           64s
```

Please let me know if you have further questions regarding this answer.

Comment: Thank you @PjoterS